# same url different environment - one succeeds the other fails with SSL error

Tags: c#, .net, ssl

The url requests warranty information from certain website.

For some reason I have to fast forward the system clock a few days for testing purpose. The behavior for browser in two environment was consistent - I got "Certificate error - Continue to this website (not recommended)." When I set back the clock to the current time warranty information was returned as expected.

However the same code in two environment behaved differently. I'm using

```
(HttpWebResponse) req.GetResponse();
```

One fails with exception : "The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel." which is as expected but the other runs successfully with warranty information in the response.

There is no special setting among the two systems and I just can't figure out why the code behave differently - the successful one.

Thanks,

Comment: What operating systems are in use?

Comment: I would bet that the failing environment doesn't trust the certificate itself or a CA in the chain. Check certmgr in both environments.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that successful one has other part of the program executed code like below, but the failed one uses default behavior.

```
public class TrustAllCertificatePolicy : System.Net.ICertificatePolicy
{
  public TrustAllCertificatePolicy() 
  {}

  public bool CheckValidationResult(ServicePoint sp, X509Certificate cert,WebRequest req, int problem)
  {
    return true;
  }
}

System.Net.ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy = new TrustAllCertificatePolicy();
```